# 15 inch Retina MBP clicky touchpad is no longer clicky on the left side

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

So I am afraid that there is no way to tell what is causing this change, whether it is that I have been wearing out the trackpad on the left side (since that is where I rest my thumb to actuate the click) or whether it is because of something else (like the battery possibly expanding).

But what is definitely different is that the trackpad's very nice tactile click feedback is no longer working properly at the left side which is where I like to use it with my thumb. The resistance force (and "click") decreases proportionally to how close to the left edge that I press down. When pressing down on the trackpad from the middle of the left edge of it, it goes down with almost no perceptible click. However, the click is registered in the OS. This is sort of okay because it means it's still functioning, but now I can't really tell when I am clicking or not so I get phantom clicks.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

Comment: I noticed that changing the forces on the unibody frame seems to affect the clickiness behavior of the trackpad. I am somehow able to, by (gently!) flexing the frame, bring back the click that I'm used to. This is just really weird.

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same issue including frame flexing effect. Can you tell, if you have managed to resolve the problem somehow, please.

Comment: I dunno. When it happens (rarely these days) I just sort of like... attempt to bend my macbook (trackpad side facing out). Not applying a lot of force or anything. It seems to bring the clicky back. *shrug*

Comment: I've having the exact same problem. Flexing it in the top right bottom left direction seems to fix the probelm, flexing it the other way makes the trackpad loose and has a "double click" effect. It's quite annoying.

Comment: The problem went away basically entirely for me months ago without me really doing anything. It's quite strange

Comment: The creaking noise I can deal with, what I can't deal with is how the trackpad feels "loose" when I flex it a certain way. I'm going to try and take off the bottom lid, then tighten all the screws inside to see if it helps.

Comment: That is a pretty good idea, it would be awesome if you report back with how that goes!

Comment: So I took off the rear cover, brushed the dust off and used compressed air to clean the fans and internals a bit then simply put the cover back on. Initial results are good, no more flexing noises, trackpad works fine. Will report if anything changes over time though. It was hard to see how the back cover can affect the tactile feeling of the trackpad since it was hidden behind the batteries, but still...